# Как запретить поворот экрана у Андроид приложения?

Tags: java, android, экран

Нужно чтобы приложение имело только вертикальную ориентацию и не поворачивалось при перевороте экрана.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В манифесте приложения у каждой Activity прописать `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`